# Magento doesn't appear any default email template

Tags: magento, templates, default, transactional-email

I'm trying to create a transactional email in magento 1.7, but when I try to add a new template the default template select is empty and I can't continue creating it.

[image]

Comment: can you show me your custom module config.xml code?

Comment: can you provide the content of the table core_email_template please ?

Comment: @KaranAdhikari Why do you whant to see the config.xml? I have several custom modules but any of them are code to change email templates. Is there any tag on config.xml witch cant make it fail?

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf my core_email_template is empty

Comment: i wanted to check your config.xml because there is some problem with your custom module's config.xml .where you are including your custom email template

Comment: HI Lorena did you solved the issue you mentioned above?I too got same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that no email is set in the database and you can wether get the data from a clean installation or set it by yourself througth the admin : System > configuration > transactionnal emails.

I would advise you the second solution that is in my opinion safier and permits to define the email as you wish with the design you want to use.

If you do not have any default template in your selectbox, you can check under the app / locale / yourlanguage / template / email if you do not have anything, you should have under the en_US folder. You can copy and adapt. If you have nothing under these two folder, you can get it from a basic installation.

Comment: The problem is precisely that I cannot create transactional emails. When I access System > transactional emails and push the add button. The system ask me to set a default template but the select control to select it is empty.